# Crash when running PyQt5 with matplotlib on iPython

Tags: python, matplotlib, ipython, pyqt5

I want to use matplotlib on my own GUI application, so decided to implement it using PyQt5. I wrote the test code below.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow

import matplotlib as mpl
mpl.use('Qt5Agg')
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


class MyApp(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.show()
        self.raise_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = MyApp()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

However, I was faced with a weird problem.
When I ran the code on iPython, there is no problem.
The 2nd running is also OK.
But, after I launched the application 3rd times and closed it, iPython freezed with some messages. The message is as follows.

```
QEventLoop: Cannot be used without QApplication
QSocketNotifier: Can only be used with threads started with Thread
```

This problem can be reproduced on my PC. Why such a crash occurs?
I use python (3.5.2), iPython (5.1.0), and matplotlib (1.5.3). PC's OS is Mac OS X (10.11.4).